# How can my custom Visual Studio project support nested projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nested, project-structure, vssdk

I'm trying to make a custom Visual Studio project type using VSProjectSystem.  I'd like my project to basically work like a SolutionFolder project type, where it is simply a container for subprojects.  The custom project will represent a whole library module and will contain the public interface code (e.g. headers for C++ libraries) and private implementation code.  The implementation code will exist in a single shared code project and a single project for each build target (e.g. Windows, WindowsPhone, XboxOne, etc).  I know that VS supports platform-specific project properties, but the build target projects aren't necessarily platform-specific (e.g. WindowsDirect3D and WindowsOpenGL).  There are other reasons to split up the build targets into separate projects as well, but that is my primary reason.

Can anyone either explain how to add support to my custom project for adding subprojects (specifically, the Add -> New Project context menu item).  Alternatively, if anyone knows of any documentation on adding nested project support, I don't mind doing my own research.  I have looked for days now and can't find any samples or tutorials or documentation on how to do this.  I know that a NestedProject project "Capability" already exists, but adding it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You want to have multiple projects together?

Comment: Yes.  I want to add a custom Module project which contains a Shared project and multiple build target projects (e.g. Windows Desktop, Windows Phone, iOS, Android, etc) which all reference the Shared project.  Basically, I want it to work like a SolutionFolder, but with a custom icon and project properties and a project template so you can add one from the New Project dialog.